# Java - Como acessar um vetor de Strings de uma Classe em outra Classe?

Tags: java, array, string

Olá,

Tenho uma classe chamada Arquivo.java, no qual realizei a leitura de um arquivo txt e aloquei as frases contidas nesse arquivo num ArrayList, podendo ser visualizado no código abaixo:

```
public void leitor() throws IOException {

    BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("arquivo.txt"));
    String linha = "";

    while (true) {
        if (linha != null) {
            arq_frases.add(linha); //arq_frases é o meu ArrayList

        } else {
            break;
        }
        linha = buffRead.readLine();
    }
    buffRead.close();
}
```

Entretanto, eu não consigo acessar essas Strings em outra classe, mesmo usando *Extends Arquivo* ou Instânciando o Objeto Arquivo em outra classe. Em todas as tentativas, eu sempre acesso o array como null. Onde estou errando?

Comment: Tente o ```static``` junto com o ```public```.

Comment: `"mesmo usando Extends Arquivo ou Instânciando o Objeto Arquivo em outra classe"`, por essa frase tenho impressão que você ainda não compreendeu os mecanismos básicos do Java, que são muito mais fundamentais e importantes que ler arquivos, recomendo estudá-los primeiro, com livros ou aulas para que seu conhecimento não fique com lacunas importantes sobre os fundamentos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A implementação abaixo está bem fiel ao código que você fez, mas agora está funcionando, comentei os problemas que vi:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Arquivo {

    private ArrayList<String> arq_frases = new ArrayList<>(); //poderia ser lowerCamelCase: "arqFrases"

    public void leitor() throws IOException { //seria melhor um nome como "ler" já que é o comportamento do objeto, "Leitor" parece o nome de um objeto

        BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("arquivo.txt")); //"arquivo.txt" poderia ser passado por parâmetro para o método ser mais reutilizável
        String linha = "";    
        while (true) {
            if (linha != null) {
                arq_frases.add(linha); //aqui adiciona-se primeiro a linha vazia, depois as linhas do arquivo
                //dessa forma, o ArrayList fica com uma String vazia no índice 0

            } else {
                break;
            }
            linha = buffRead.readLine();
        }
        buffRead.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arquivo arquivo = new Arquivo(); //Como coloquei o ArrayList como variável de instância, precisaremos instanciar a classe Arquivo
        try {
            arquivo.leitor(); //carrega arq_frases com as linhas do arquivo
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Ops! problema ao ler o arquivo!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (String linha : arquivo.arq_frases) { //acessando o ArrayList da instância
            System.out.println(linha);
        }
    }
}
```

Abaixo segue uma implementação alternativa usando a classe `Files`:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Arquivo {

    public static List<String> lerLinhasDeArquivo(String caminhoDoArq) throws IOException {
        return Files.lines(new File(caminhoDoArq).toPath(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        lerLinhasDeArquivo("arquivo.txt").forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Neste exemplo, `lerLinhasDeArquivo(...)` é estático, e portanto não é necessário instanciar `Arquivo` para acessá-lo.